# Golden Gate replication from primary to secondary database, WARNING OGG-01154 Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for Oracle, rgg1ab.prm: SQL error 1403

Tags: oracle, database-replication

I am using golden gate to replicate data from primary to secondary. I have inserted records in the primary database, but replication abdends with error message

> WARNING OGG-01154  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for Oracle, rgg1ab.prm:  SQL error 1403 mapping primaryDB_GG1.TB_myTableName to secondaryDB.TB_myTableName OCI Error ORA-01403: no data found, SQL < UPDATE ......

The update statement has all the columns from table in the where clause.
Whereas there is no such update statement in the application with so many columns in where clause.

Can you help on this issue. Why Golden Gate replication is converting insert in to update while replication.

Comment: I think this will be better suitted on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I know this very old, but if you haven't figured out a solution, please provide your prm file if you can. You may a parameter in there that is converting inserts to updates based upon a PK already existing in the target database. It is likely that handlecollisions or CDR is set.

Answer (score 0):

For replication, you might have already enabled the transaction log in the source db. Now, you need to run from ggsci:

> "ADD TRANDATA schema_name.table_name, COLS(...)"

In the COLS part, you need to mention the Column/Columns(comma seperated) that can be used to identify a unique record (You can mention the unique indexed columns if present). If there is no unique index on the table and you are not sure of what columns could be used to uniquely identify a row, then just run from ggsci:

> "ADD TRANDATA schema_name.table_name"

Then Golden gate will start logging all the necessary columns for uniquely identifying a row. 
Note: This should be done before you start the replication process.